# ssh can't resolve second host from config when using -F

Tags: ssh, configuration

In order to access a certain machine I need to get through a proxy and then via a jumphost, before I'm at the desired location.

For this I'm using a config file like this:

```
### jumphost
Host jmp
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port
  User user
  ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.name.com port %h %p

### box
Host box
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  User user
  ProxyCommand ssh mgmtbox netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

This works perfectly fine as long as the config file is in its set location.
However, if I want to specify this config file with the -F flag ("*ssh -F configfile box*"), I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname jmp: Name or service not known
```

The problem starts only with the second host. If I use "*ssh -F configfile jmp*" the command works fine.

I'm a bit lost here, since the config file works perfectly fine until it is used via the -F flag.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works perfectly fine as long as the config file is in its set location. However, if I want to specify this config file with the -F flag ("ssh -F configfile box"), I get the following error:

The problem is that while running proxy command, you don't specify the configuration location. It is completely unrelated `ssh` instance and therefore it does not know the hostname.

Using

```
ProxyCommand ssh -F configfile mgmtbox netcat -w 120 %h %p
```

will make it work for you. Also the other thing pointed out in the other answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem

> HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port

I think it should be

```
HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port port
```

The ssh config `HostName`parameter takes a hostname, not a hostname:port

Comment: Apparently ip:port works fine in the config file. I just tried it without and can't connect anymore.